# creating a new span tags inside a div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a typing game for my portfolio project . I am new to programming .
I want to render every random word in a div and every character wrapped in a span tag inside that div.
i achieved rendering the divs but wrapping the characters inside span tags seems impossible . i tried many ways but couldn't get it to work.

closest i got is this function which takes the word and parent as a param and creates spans in that parent element

```
    function spanifyWords(word, parent){
     for (i=0 ; i< word.length; i++){
         let newSpan = document.createElement("span");
         newSpan = parent.appendChild(newSpan);
         newSpan.innerHTML += word[i];
            }
        }
```

if i call this function with for example

```
spanifyWords("hello", wordsContainer) ;
```

then it creates 5 span tags which each char inside the main div .
this one works fine as long as i dont call it in other function which renders divs inside the main div(wordsContainer).

```
function renderDivs(n){
            for (i=0; i<n; i++){
                let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*wordsCount)
                let randomWord = newArray[randomIndex];
                let newDiv = document.createElement("div")   
                 newDiv = wordsContainer.appendChild(newDiv)
                newDiv.innerHTML += spanifyWords(randomWord, newDiv);   //  this needs attention
            
        }

    }
```

my guess is that I'm doing something wrong at the last line of second function . either function is not able to configure the parent or Javascript innerHTML doesn't take a function as a value.

can someone please tell me what is wrong with the second function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The for loop's `i = 0` should be `let i = 0;` otherwise it's set to the global scope
- No need to reset `newSpan = parent.append(newSpan);` just use `parent.append(newSpan);`
- Use just `wordsContainer.append(newDiv);` without the `innerHTML =`  - that task is already done in the `spanifyWords` function
- Use `const` where due

```js
const wordsContainer = document.querySelector("#wordsContainer");
const newArray = ["hello", "world", "lorem", "ipsum"];
const wordsCount = newArray.length;

function spanifyWords(word, parent){
  for (let i=0 ; i < word.length; i++){
    const newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    parent.append(newSpan);
    newSpan.textContent = word[i];
  }
}

function renderDivs(n){
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsCount);
    const randomWord = newArray[randomIndex];
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    wordsContainer.append(newDiv);
    spanifyWords(randomWord, newDiv);
  }
}

renderDivs(6);
```

```css
#wordsContainer * {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  font: 1rem/1 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <div id="wordsContainer"></div>
```

Here's also a slight variation on the above code:

```js
// Utility functions
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const repeat = (n, cb) => [...Array(n)].forEach((_, i) => cb(i));

// Wordify
const elWords = el("#wordsContainer");
const words = ["hello", "world", "lorem", "ipsum"];

const spanify = (word) => [...word].reduce((a, x) => a + `<span>${x}</span>`, "");

function renderDivs(n){
  repeat(n, () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    const randomWord = words[randomIndex];
    const elDiv = elNew("div", { innerHTML: spanify(randomWord) });
    elWords.append(elDiv);
  });
}

renderDivs(6);
```

```css
#wordsContainer * {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  font: 1rem/1 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordsContainer"></div>
```

Comment: wow Thanks this worked on the first try . God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

The `spanifyWords` function already adds the span elements to the container, so there is no need to set the `innerHTML` at all (in fact, you were setting it to `undefined` as `spanifyWords` does not return anything). Directly use `spanifyWords(randomWord, newDiv);` instead.

Furthermore, declare each loop counter with `let i = 0;` so that it is scoped to the block instead of global.

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/v9tmfksL/

Comment: thanks for your help . it works now . i was doing serious mistakes in the code . i was trying to solve this riddle since two weeks now and was mentally exhausted by it .